# Azure Dashboard - Show failed vs Successfull request on 1 specific request

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, dashboard

I am new to application insights and I got relatively far. I am now busy setting up a dashboard and would really like to be able to display a chart or something on a specific request : Lets say - www.myapi.com/dashboard. Total request = 100, Failed request = 22. How can I achieve to display this kind of info. Or a site that can be helpfull writing queries

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview - there are links to tutorials at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please help accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show failed vs Successfull request on 1 specific request

In application insights logs, if the request is failed, then the **success property** is set to **False**; if the request is successful, the **success property** is set to **True**. Screenshot as below:

[image]

So if you want to compare the successful request with failed request, for a specific request, use the query below:

```
requests 
| where url == "the specified request url" 
| summarize count() by success
```

After run the query, click the "Chart" button to generate chart-> then click the "pin to dashboard" button. Please refer to the screenshot for more details:

[image]

Then nav to the dashboard, and select a proper Time range(no more than 31 days.). For more details, refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

At last, you can see the successful request vs failed request chart:

[image]

Comment: a bit late, but its exactly how I did this. Its confirms that I was on the right track. Thank you